# Grails - A previous call to redirect(..) has already redirected

Tags: grails

In Grails app, occasionally seeing "Cannot issue redirect" in logs:

2011-04-27 12:18:40,469 [TP-Processor13] ERROR GrailsExceptionResolver - Cannot issue a redirect(..) here. A previous call to redirect(..) has already redirected the response.
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.CannotRedirectException: Cannot issue a redirect(..) here. A previous call to redirect(..) has already redirected the response.
       at com.coach.LoginController$_closure2.doCall(LoginController.groovy:90)
...

Not sure how to track this down.  Any ideas or suggestions?

Todd

Comment: What is here: LoginController.groovy:90 ??

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Check the login controller; it seems like you are not returning from the action after redirect. *E.g.*:

```
if (some condition) {
    redirect ()
    return  // should return from here to finish the action, otherwise the rest of the code will be executed
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Although this question has been answered, I figured I'd share my experience for future trawlers.  Hope it helps.

This happened to me because I wasn't doing a `return` after the redirect:

```
    if (test) {
        flash.message = "Error message."
        redirect(action: "list")
    }

    switch ( params.test ) {
        case "value": 
            redirect(action: "value", id: callInstance.id, version: callInstance.version)
```

After a redirect, Grails will keep going if there's no `return`. In my case, it hit the `switch` and went on to the second redirect, which is where the error arose.  The code should look like the following:

```
    if (test) {
        flash.message = "Error message."
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }

    switch ( params.test ) {
        case "value": 
            redirect(action: "value", id: callInstance.id, version: callInstance.version)
            return
```

This code has been anonymised of course ;)

*EDIT*

Aw geeze. I just realized that this is [Sachin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/728538/sachin-anand)'s answer :/  Well, I'll leave it as an additional example.

Answer (score 1):

You can only redirect once.  If you are moving from controller method A -> B -> C, B should really be a service method that then passes it's results to controller method C, not a controller method.

```
class TemplateController {
  def templateService

  def A() {
    def results = templateService.B(params.input)

    redirect action: 'C', params: ['results': results]
  }

  def C() {
    return params.results
  }
}
```