# Grails 3 interceptors for authentication?

Tags: authentication, interceptor, grails-3.0

I am experimenting with Grails 3 [Interceptors](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/single.html#interceptors). Given the following interceptor:

```
class AuthInterceptor {
    AuthInterceptor() {
        matchAll().includes(controller:"account")
    }

    // Intercept anything under /account.
    boolean before() {
        User user = SimpleSecurityUtils.getCurrentUser()
        if(user != SimpleSecurityUtils.anonymous) {
            // Only get here if the user is currently authenticated. Redirect them to where they want to go.
            true
        } else {
            redirect(controller: auth, action: signin)
            true    ??
        }
    }

    boolean after() { true }

    void afterView() {
        // no-op
    }
}
```

1. `matchAll().includes(...)` doesn't actually exist on the [`Matcher`](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/api/grails/interceptors/Matcher.html) object. So how do I actually say "*only intercept requests to the `AccountController`*"?
2. If you follow the auth logic, if the user is currently `anonymous` (not logged in), I want to redirect them to the `AuthController#signin` action, which will present them with a login screen. It doesn't appear that the `redirect(...)` closure is available to interceptors...so how do I perform this redirect **safely**? Furthermore, how do I "save off" the URL we are currently intercepting so that, after successful login, the user can yet again be redirected to the originally-requested URL?

I say **safely** above because I've had issues with Grails `CannotRedirectException`s being thrown if too many redirects keep getting tossed around, and those errors are usually assuaged by returning after performing a redirect per [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5813669/4009451).

Comment: not by any chance you would have a more elaborate example to provide? Looking at just this now, not much to go buy thus far.

Answer (score 1):

For #1, match( controller: "account" ) should do the trick.  Don't know the answer to #2.